# can a mysql select query in C language return a field with the special characters escaped?

Tags: mysql, c

1- string = `a'b"c\d`

2- escaped_string = `a\'b\"c\\d`

3- make an insert query that inserts escaped_string in some table field.

4- make a select query that returns the inserted value.

The returned value is: `a'b"c\d`

Is there a way to get the select query to return  `a\'b\"c\\d`  ?
(I understand that i can escape it again).

Comment: Do you want the database to store a'b"c\d or a\'b\"c\d?

Comment: I want the database to store a'b"c\d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QUOTE()` function of mysql:

```
mysql> select data from x;
+---------+
| data    |
+---------+
| a'b"c\d |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select quote(data) from x;
+-------------+
| quote(data) |
+-------------+
| 'a\'b"c\\d' |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This should exactly do what you are looking for. Note that the `"` doesn't need to be escaped here, so `QUOTE()` doesn't escape it, too.